# HTML Conditional Comment Support in Firefox. How the Following Piece of Code Works

Tags: html, firefox

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <!--[if lte IE 9]>
    <html class="ie lte9" lang="en">
    <![endif]-->
    <!--[if !IE ]><!-->
    <html lang="en">
    <!--<![endif]-->
    <!--[if gte IE 10]>
    <html class="ie gte10" lang="en">
    <![endif]-->
```

I know conditional HTML comment is for IE only and Firefox etc do not understand that.

**How the above conditional html tag works correctly in Firefox and Chrome when *NOT IE* is in middle of the alternatives?** I see that line (`<html lang="en">`) highlighted in Firefox and chrome. It means FF and chrome understood those correctly and chosen correct tag for itself!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that it's highlighted correctly on SO should give you a hint.

Conditional comments are pieces of text that, from an xml point of view, are normal comments.  That is, everything between `<!--` and `-->` is ignored.

Firefox and chrome follow these rules, and so happily ignore the text above and below your  `<html lang="en">` part.

IE has special parsing rules, so that if a comment contains the text `[if * IE *]>stuff<!<![endif]-->`, the "stuff" is parsed as html (even though it's strictly a comment).  And the other way around, html that is wedged between comments containing the `[if !IE]` comments, is ignored, even though strictly they should not be.

Comment: Ok, I have not noticed this part: `<!-->` in that condition. It is closing the comment for FF and Chrome. This is what you want to convey ? If yes, then your answer is correct. :)

Comment: @SatyaPrakash `-->` closes the comment.  The `<!` in front is irrelevant.